# Does the weather outside make a diference in oven temp. for baking

Tags: baking, bread

I know that the humidity can make a difference on how your bread might turn out. Do you ever have to adjust the temp. on the oven depending on the weather? I finally found a good bread recipe that my husband really liked. I made it again and the crust was really hard. I did every thing the same. It was colder out side when I made the first one. The bread tasted really good like the other one it's just the crust was very hard. I melted butter on it just like the first one. I always put melted butter on my bread when I take it out of the oven.

Comment: Did you determine your bread rise time by a watch or by visual appearance? Did you notice any difference in oven spring?

Comment: @Stephie.  What is an oven spring, or did you mean the oven in Spring.  Personally I do not believe that the ambient temperature should make that much difference, even if you moved from the equator to the north pole.

Comment: @dougal2.0.0 *oven spring* is the term for the expansion of the bread in the oven. That's when the slashes open or the crust tears, for example. The behavior of the bread in the oven can tell a lot about the state of the dough. Ambient temperature and humidity can have a huge influence on the bread.

Comment: (Speaking from experience - six years of baking artisanal bread in a wood-fired oven in a communal bake house.)

Comment: @Stephie. Ah I call that rising, thus the confusion.  My baking skills are a bit rusty - not even rustic!  I don't think dougal could cope with a communal bake house!

Comment: @Stephie I think you mean that the bread is affected by weather, but before the bake - is that right?

Comment: @ChrisH Exactly. And if one doesn't take that into account, the bread might be at another "stage" when put into the oven, hence the different results. That's what I'm trying to find out from OP.

Answer (score 1):

A properly calibrated oven with a good thermistor will not be impacted by external temperatures or environmental factors.  While, as you mentioned, humidity and environmental factors can impact cooking and baking, which influences the end product, they will not impact the temperature of the oven itself.  I believe the problem is more related to the varying environmental factors, rather than the cooking temperature of the oven.  As such, it might require a change in baking time, and more close monitoring the bread, rather than adjusting the temperature at which you are baking.

With that being said, I would suggest using an external oven thermometer/thermistor to confirm that there is no need for oven calibration [ie make sure that the temperature of the oven is what it was set to].  I have seen ovens begin overheating/underheating within a few days span, when the thermistor went bad.  Also, it might help to make note of the ambient humidity and the results of each batch of bread you make.  As you notice differences, you could take notes of what works best at differing levels of humidity, and therefore be prepared in the future to adjust according to environmental changes.